# Is there a global HTML attribute like title or alt that i can use to store text for a tooltip dialog?

Tags: html, tags, tooltip

I use jquery to render a tooltip when i move my mouse hover some html tags. In this case it's the span tag. I would like to store in that span tag the text to be displayed into the tooltip.

I use most span tag but if i store my text into "title" attribute, my browser shows also a tooltip dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using a custom `data-*` attribute, such as (for example):

```
<span data-tooltipText="text to show with the tooltip plugin">Text here</span>
```

These attributes are valid under HTML 5 (and will work under HTML 4, albeit they won't validate).

References:

- [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; I'm glad to have been of help. =)

Comment: You could also take a look at [jQuery(...).data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) if you use jQuery.